# Review audit failed for an obvious attempted answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing I came across this first answer, which was a review audit:
[image]

I reviewed it as **No Action Needed** as the user tried to answer the question and in my opinion it was a valid suggestion. Now I am seeing the message:

*You have made too many incorrect reviews....Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.*

Can someone tell me how this audit is valid ?

If it isn't valid shouldn't we add a button next to *I Understand*, something that says *I Disagree* (specifying why I disagree with this audit)?

[**When An Answer is Not An Answer**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553)

[**One Liner Answers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156951)

Comment: _How_ is there no action needed, there? This is a textbook _"I'm having this problem too"_ answer that should be downvoted / flagged / deleted!

Answer (score 4):

This is a textbook *"I'm having this problem too"* answer that should have been downvoted / flagged / deleted.

It does contain a minor explanation what's happening, but it in no way *answers* a question.

Comment: The answer doesn't say *I'm having this problem too...*, it says *I had this problem too...and this is how I fixed it*, is that wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't say how he fixed it. It only says what the problem is.

Comment: yes, hence the solution, in this case: *load Bootstrap before calling the tab function*

Comment: That is not mentioned in the answer, not to mention explained how to. And as I can see from the comments there, other answers _did_ explain how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand why you would say there is no action needed, because the answer does contain a clue on how to fix it. But it's not much more than a *clue*, it's not a real answer. The main problem with it is that it is very vague:

> the problem was that bootstrap wasnt loading before the tab function was called

In itself, this doesn't really answer the question. How did the answerer get it fixed, what did he need to do *exactly* to fix his problem? It would be better to elaborate on the answer with a code sample, like:

> The problem was that I was calling the `.tab()` function, but jQuery wasn't loaded yet. I still had to add the script to my page:
>
> ```html
> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/>
> ```
>
> After that I was able to get the tabs working:
>
> ```js
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('#my-tabs').tab( // do magic here );
> });
> ```

This way, it's more clear where the problem is coming from and more importantly it gives a proper illustration on how to fix it.

As a rule of thumb, answers of only 1 or 2 sentences need close attention as they are often of poor quality and need moderation of some kind.

Comment: I agree the user should have elaborated a bit more, in such cases, wouldn't it be ideal to let the user know that he/she needs to elaborate more? What I don't understand is why the review audit failed as that was an attempted answer which did make sense.

Comment: @Criesto Well, the whole point is that it doesn't make sense. It provides no real solution. To give a real-world example, it would be the same if you told me you're thirsty and I say: "Yeah, so was I, but then I drank some milk". It tells you that you could drink some milk as well, but it doesn't say where you can get it. It would be better for me to say: "Yeah, I know that problem, but if you drink some milk, it will go away. You can get some in the Milk Market across the street.". That makes a lot more sense and actually helps you.

Comment: @Oldskool: That's exactly what I've been trying to tell the OP... +1